# how to change the cursor of disabled ImageButton in ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, css, cursor, imagebutton

I have a dynamic generated ImageButtons in a ListView, In ItemDataBound if an image have no link i need to make it disabled, i have tried the following,

```
                img.Enabled = False
                img.DescriptionUrl = "javascript:void(0);"
                img.PostBackUrl = "javascript:void(0);"
                img.CssClass = "imageButtonClass"
                img.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "pointer")
```

CSS:

```
.imageButtonClass
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

That's made the targeted images disabled in all browsers , however, The cursor changed to pointer in IE only. Not in Firefox and Chrome!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Image button already should have cursor:pointer by default. Can you post some renderd HTML for the button at jsfiddle.net to show the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have declared a doctype. That is the source of most cross-browser inconsistency issues.

Most new pages should be using the HTML 5 doctype as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It might also help if you compare your example with this working one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor. As you can see, this works fine in FireFox. Note the doctype declaration at the top of the page.